# How to write uwsgi ini file equivalent to a uwsgi command

Tags: python, uwsgi, ini

I am testing an application in uWsgi server using the command,

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file myapp.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

That starts the application on 9090 port. I want to write a `.ini` file for this. But I am stuck with `--http :9090` part. How it will be written in the `ini` file? So far my `uwsgi.ini` file looks like this,

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = myapp.py
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```

Comment: found the solution in [Here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-web2py). It will be written as `http = :9090`. Don't no how I skipped it before posting the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration directives and command line options are managed by the same parser: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html

In the case of the ini format you only need to remove the double dashes before the option.

Comment: Thanks. I found it right after i posted the question.

Answer (score 4):

uwisgi.ini

```
stats = :1717 --stats-http
```

Documentation: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StatsServer.html

Comment: this is what I am searching for. Thanks mate.

Comment: This does not work and it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
stats = 0.0.0.0:6000
stats-http = true
```